# BSoD WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR triggered by ffmpeg

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, bsod

Have been experiencing this BSoD on and off, but I can reliably trigger it with ffmpeg and libx264, which is sad because I need that. So far I havn't identified any other applications that trigger it (but there must be, since it also happened once or twice when I wasn't running ffmpeg).

I've read online that it's most likely a hardware problem, but two different versions of Prime95 can keep running for minutes without any errors, yet ffmpeg triggers the BSoD as soon as file output starts (I guess as soon as libx264 starts working).

I'm running the latest UEFI/BIOS for my mainboard which should have included the latest CPU microcode.

I've been following a tutorial to analyze the minidump, but the results don't mean anything to me.

```
WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffd108d7da4028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000b2000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000070005, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  System manufacturer

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  System Product Name

SYSTEM_SKU:  SKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  0802

BIOS_DATE:  09/06/2017

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  PRIME X299-DELUXE

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev 1.xx

DUMP_TYPE:  2

DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0xc
  Insufficient Dumpfile Size
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffd108d7da4028

BUGCHECK_P3: b2000000

BUGCHECK_P4: 70005

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CPU_COUNT: 10

CPU_MHZ: e10

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 55

CPU_STEPPING: 4

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,55,4,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 200002B'00000000 (cache) 200002B'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  ffmpeg.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  10-19-2017 18:26:05.0713

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.16299.15 x86fre

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffbf00`466cd8c8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  81a83ae0317433a47fcc36991983df3b6e638b71

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  6e16edd8c7dd677734fdbcd2397a2e35e9fae964

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  76cd06466d098060a9eb26e5fd2a25cb1f3fe0a3

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel

IMAGE_NAME:  GenuineIntel

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

TARGET_TIME:  2017-10-19T16:20:28.000Z

OSBUILD:  16299

OSSERVICEPACK:  15

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2017-09-29 03:53:04

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160101.0800

BUILDLAB_STR:  WinBuild

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.16299.15

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  58e

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x124_genuineintel_processor_mae

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {7c95de0c-286c-8226-45c2-422b4de101d6}
```

---

```
THREAD ffffd108e102f080  Cid 067c.0c88  Teb: 000000000036b000 Win32Thread: 0000000000000000 RUNNING on processor c
Not impersonating
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80081d66874
Owning Process            ffffd108e0ef1080       Image:         ffmpeg.exe
Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
fffff78000000000: Unable to get shared data
Wait Start TickCount      3906         
Context Switch Count      79             IdealProcessor: 0             
ReadMemory error: Cannot get nt!KeMaximumIncrement value.
UserTime                  00:00:00.000
KernelTime                00:00:00.000
Win32 Start Address 0x00007ff9f7d4a940
Stack Init ffff84855540f550 Current ffff84855540f240
Base ffff848555410000 Limit ffff848555409000 Call 0000000000000000
Priority 6 BasePriority 6 PriorityDecrement 0 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
ffffbf00`466cd8c8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
```

---

```
12: kd> dps ffff848555409000 ffff848555409000
ffff8485`55409000  00000000`00000000
```

---

```
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffd108d7da4028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d348f6093222fe
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 864
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 10/19/2017 16:20:28 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffd108d7da40a8
Section       @ ffffd108d7da4180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Micro-Architectural Error
Flags         : 0x00
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000050654
Processor ID  : 0x000000000000000c

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffd108d7da40f0
Section       @ ffffd108d7da4240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 64
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x000000000000000c
CPU Id        : 54 06 05 00 00 08 10 0c - bf fb fe 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffd108d7da4138
Section       @ ffffd108d7da4280
Offset        : 600
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : Unknown (Proc 12 Bank 0)
  Status      : 0xb200000000070005
```

Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was fixed by raising the CPU core voltage by 0.025V.

Interesting though that stress tests like Prime95 don't trigger this problem. Looks like I'll have to add a real world test like libx264 to my overclocking toolchain.